# Where is a better place to place Laravel Migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm creating an erp with laravel + larvel nova, a rest api with laravel and frontend with vuejs. My doubt is: where should i build my database migration as better practice, should i put my migration in my erp project or in my api rest project. Both will use the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create your migration in **Rest Api** beacuse **api most work is in database** and you want to **give data**(which is in Database) to user in most cases **with Api**!